# Process.Start in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, file, process, uwp

I want to run a file (video, music, picture..) from my UWP application. For WPF I can use `Process.Start(path)` method, but this method is now available for UWP. I found that probably I should use `FullTrustProcessLauncher` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher), but I don't get how does it work. Can someone write me here some very example how to use it or what else and how can I use for this problem, when I have only a `path` of the file? Thank you.

Comment: [Launch the default app for a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-the-default-app-for-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this.  This will open a wmv

```
 Windows.System.LauncherOptions options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
 options.ContentType = "video/x-ms-wmv";
 Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(fileUrl), options);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the OP wrote, when you only have a file path, you can use the following asynchronous code.

```cs
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.System;

// ...

await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path));
```